# Django Python current logged User

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my queryset I need to check status of post and if User mentioned in that post is the same as logged User. How can I get current logged User?

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(Q(status='Done') & (Q(person_1_username=current_logged_user) | Q(person_2_username=current_logged_user)))
```

I know I should use something like code below, but I don't know how to get that value to 'current_logged_user'

```
def my_view(request):
   username = None
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
      username = request.user.username
```

models.py

```
res_person_1_username = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=40)
res_person_2_username = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=40)
```

Comment: Share your models. When is a user mentioned?

Comment: In your code you are already getting the current user, twice.

Comment: `request.user.is_authenticated` is a property and not a function. You don't have to put paranthesis.

Comment: Current User is not mentioned in models.py, I have defined 'responsible people' in models.py. I need to get username of the currently logged in user to give permission to update the post. Question updated with 'models.py'.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this? where eihter person1 or person2 are the actual authenticated user

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(Q(status='Done') & (Q(person_1_username=request.user) | Q(person_2_username=request.user)))
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, when I put it like that, I get error 'NameError: name 'request' is not defined'